# how to make divs clikable after posting

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I'm busy to create an online agenda.
I have 3 drop down menu's where you can select the year, month and week you want to see.
Then with out a page refresh the div's(day's with there number for example you selected februari 2008 and you get 1 feb thuiesday ect..) are printed. Those divs must be made click able so a popup/light box will open the selected day with the apointments.
(the divs are an callback form handler.php and there 35 of them so i hope i can do it with one function)

i made a function called test and added that on the onlclick event but it dindt work(but the alert was shown when i started the page and hadn't posted or cliked anything)

`$(function test(){alert("test");`

and i made all div's the same class(klik) so that if something with the class klik is cliked that the alert ad to be shown but also that dint work .

`$('.klik').click(function(){
alert("test");
});});`

the css of the divs:

`div#a1                 {
        width:100px;
        height:110px;
        margin-left:99px;
        margin-top:-111px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
        }`

the creation of the divs in handler.php
`$b=0;

```
            while ($b < 35)
                    {
        echo "<div id='a$b' name='b' class='klik'>";
        echo "<p>test ".$b."" ;
        echo "</div>";
        $b++;
        }`
```

I hope i gave u enough information that mabey you guys can help me
thanks Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into event delegation, which is implemented in jQuery as [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

So, instead of

```
$('.klik').click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

try

```
$('.klik').live('click', function() { alert('test'); });
```

Comment: This was what I was about to suggest

Answer (score 1):

is your function to make the divs clickable in the onload event ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.klik').click(function(){ alert("test"); });}); 
});
```